# Why can I no longer find the "Big Deal" card game under that name?

Tags: identify-this-game

Why can't I find the card game "BIG DEAL"? I used to have it several years ago but can't find it anywhere since? It had cards with images of different valuables a person might own- 'Gold bars' 'cash under mattress' 'stamp collection' etc. Were there legal issues?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we can't answer why a game is no longer for sale.

Comment: @JoeW There certainly are games where we _can_ answer that question e.g. [Ankh-Morpork](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/91312/discworld-ankh-morpork) is out of print because of a licensing dispute between Pratchett's estate and the publisher.

Comment: @philip-kendall Yes! that's almost exactly it, though I'm baffled as to why the game under the old name just doesn't turn up any results. Legal stuff?

Comment: @bensvensson changing this to ["where can I buy" makes this 100% off topic](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/); I'd suggest you revert the edit if you want any chance of it being reopened.

Comment: @philipkendall thanks. Gosh being new here is hard There's so much to know before anything. Golly, okay I suppose reverting the question would be best.

Comment: @bensvensson welcome aboard, regardless! It takes a bit to adjust to SE's format, since it is different from most (all?) other online forums. Hope you stick around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This game is now known as [Cover Your Assets](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/121193/cover-your-assets) and is readily available in 2023. Based on the [publishing history on BoardGameGeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/121193/cover-your-assets/versions), my *hypothesis* is that is was renamed when the publisher changed from Schmidt Spiele to Grandpa Beck's Games in around 2018.